# Call to a member function getPathName() on array

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm uploading a multi file array to my server in Laravel.

When I log the files using `$request->file('files')` I get:

```
[2018-11-12 16:10:03] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'test-pdf.pdf',
     'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
  1 => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'test-pdf.pdf',
     'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
  2 => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'test-pdf.pdf',
     'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

I want to access each file in the array and get the pathname like so:

```
$files = $request->files;
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
  Log::debug($file->getPathName());
}
```

However this throws the following error:

```
local.ERROR: Call to a member function getPathName() on array {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function getPathName() on array at /home/vagrant/Projects/business-risk-portal/app/Http/Controllers/FileController.php:68)
```

How can access the file path for each of those uploaded files?

**UPDATE**
If I try this:

```
$files = $request->files;
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
   $temp_path = $request->file('tmp.' . $key);
   Log::debug($temp_path->getPathName());
}
```

I get:

```
Call to a member function getPathName() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function getPathName() on null at /home/vagrant/Projects/business-risk-portal/app/Http/Controllers/FileController.php:69)
```

Comment: i'm assuming $request->files and $request->file('files') return different values...  Maybe $request->files returns an array of all files versus files with the input name of `files`.

Comment: Is your `$request->files` part of the Request injected to handle the form posts?
If so, can you do `print_r($request->files)`? It is possible it is returning the information as the `$_FILES` would, meaning they are arrays and not objects

Comment: @Devon you're right. You can write that as the answer and I'll make it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request->files` will return a multi-dimensional array of all files, while `$request->file('files')` will return an array of only the files relating to the `files` input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

Server side:

```
$files = $request->file('myfiles');

foreach($files as $file) {
    $target = $file->move(storage_path('files'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $path = $target->getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $target->getFileName();
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post" action="/myfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="file" name="myfiles[]" class="form-control" multiple />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```